# How to give relative path of script in system function in C?

Tags: c, linux

My .c code is in "src" directory and space.sh is in "bin "directory. In the given code I have given full path of space.sh. when I run the code, its working fine but when I use relative path in the system function it will have error like path not found(system(function commented part)).What is going on wrong here? I want relative path only with respect to my .c code (or relative to "practice" directory)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
//system("../bin/space.sh");
system("/home/amitk/projects/amit_bk/practice/bin/space.sh");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The Current Working Directory may not be where your executable is located. You can use `argv[0]` which is passed to `main` to ascertain the path to use.

Comment: Where does the executable get saved after you compile?

Comment: @AymanAl-Qadhi in bin file

Comment: Then there is no need to specify the path. Just specify the file name directly.

Answer (score 0):

A path relative to your .c code makes no sense, as the .exe can end up anywhere, for example if you distribute your application without code.

If you use relative paths they will be relative to the current path when the .exe is being run. If it's double-clicked in explorer it will be the same path as the .exe, but it is for example possible to make a shortcut with your .exe as "Target" but with a different "Start in" location, so you should never assume the current path is where the .exe file is.

You can determine the location of the .exe file using `argv[0]` if you define your main function as `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. So if needed you could strip the .exe filename from `argv[0]` to determine the .exe's path.